# 3D Feature extraction using Windows Kinect in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, kinect

I am trying to extract the 3D coordinates of an object using the Kinect for Windows camera. The object to be extracted will be highlighted either with a vivid color, or graphic that can be recognized using feature extraction.

I have used MATLAB and Kinect for both feature extraction and 3D co-ordinate extraction before, however I am having a problem trying to merge the techniques together.

A really simple way to highlight the object, and extract it as a feature in a 2D image is to draw 5 circles really close to each other on the object, Then put it view of the camera and use `CenterCoords = imfindcircles(image, [15 20]);` to extract the co-ordinates of all circles (within a radius range) in the image. You can then remove all circles in the image that don't have 5 similar circles in there immediate proximity, and extract the co-ordinate of the center circle.

But how can I extend this idea to 3D? How can I extract the 3D co-ordinates of a highlighted object using the Kinect Camera?

Answer (score 0):

To use 3-D you would have to use the Depth Values, and maybe a combination of Color Edge filtering techniques as well. The idea is to use the Depth values of the object, plus the color edges as your feature selections.

Use a Machine Learning algorithm such as kNN to find your color edges and possible Depth values that are similar to the object.

These values come as an array of pixel and depths.